# SQL Server 2016 Install Error 2337 Could Not Close File

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 on a fresh install of Windows Server 2016. Every time I run the install I encounter the same error message pasted below.

Crawling the internet has brought me no luck. The most common response I have seen is corrupted installation media. At this point I have tested 3 different ISO files and got the same result each time. I have also tried unzipping the ISO and installing that way.

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  Failed: see details
>   below   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068051679   Start time:
>   2019-12-13 08:44:26   End time:                      2019-12-13
>   09:13:05   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>   information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
>   the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup
>   process again.   Next step for Browser:         Use the following
>   information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process
>   again.   Next step for ComponentUpdate: Use the following information
>   to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  XXXXXX   Machine
>   processor count:       4   OS version:                    Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (10.0.14393)   OS service pack:
>   OS region:                     United States   OS language:
>   English (United States)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
>   architecture:          64 Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2016    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016   Type: 
>   RTM   Version:                       13   Installation location:
>   C:\NEW_SQL\x64\setup\   Installation edition:          Standard
>
> Slipstream:                    True   SP Level
>   2
>
> Product Update Status:   Success: KB 4052908
>
> Product Updates Selected for Installation:   Title:
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2016  with SP2   Knowledge Based Article:
>   KB 4052908   Version:                       13.2.5026.0
>   Architecture:                  x64   Language:
>   1033
>
> Update Source:                 Slipstream
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>   XXX\xxxxx   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE: 
>   Automatic   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup   ASCOLLATION:
>   Latin1_General_CI_AS   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
>   ASDATADIR:                     Data   ASLOGDIR:
>   Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1   ASSERVERMODE:
>   MULTIDIMENSIONAL   ASSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTELSVCACCT:
>      ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CLTCTLRNAME:
>      CLTRESULTDIR:                     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                    CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>      CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\ConfigurationFile.ini   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:
>      CTLRUSERS:                        ENABLERANU:
>   false   ENU:                           true   EXTSVCACCOUNT:
>      EXTSVCPASSWORD:                   FEATURES:
>   SQLENGINE   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:
>      FTSVCACCOUNT:                     FTSVCPASSWORD:
>      HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS: 
>   true   INDICATEPROGRESS:              false   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:
>   G:\Data   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\   INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
>   INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER   ISSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISSVCPASSWORD:                  
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   ISTELSVCACCT:
>      ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
>   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:               MATRIXNAME:
>      MRCACHEDIRECTORY:                 NPENABLED:
>   0   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:                  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:
>      PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:
>      PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              
>   PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBPORTRANGE:
>      PBSCALEOUT:                    false   PID:
>   *****   QUIET:                         false   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:                             RSINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultNativeMode   RSSHPINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultSharePointMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SAPWD:                         *****   SECURITYMODE:
>   SQL   SQLBACKUPDIR:                  G:\Backup   SQLCOLLATION:
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:
>   XXX\xxxxxx   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true   SQLSVCPASSWORD:
>   *****   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           XXX\xxxxxx   SQLTELSVCACCT:
>   NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             
>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic   SQLTEMPDBDIR:
>   T:\Data   SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:
>   64   SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             6144   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
>   G:\Log   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:
>   1024   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  G:\Data   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
>   G:\Log   SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   TCPENABLED:
>   1   UIMODE:                        Normal   UpdateEnabled:
>   true   UpdateSource:                  Slipstream   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:
>   false   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of
>   the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.   Next
>   Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the
>   error, and then try the setup process again.   Component name:
>   SQL Server Setup Support Files   Component error code:          2337
>   Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log 
>   Error description:             The installer has encountered an
>   unexpected error. The error code is 2337. Could not close file:
>   Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.dll GetLastError:
>   0.   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%402337
>
> Feature:                       SQL Browser   Status:
>   Failed: see logs for details   Reason for failure:            An error
>   occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for
>   the feature to fail.   Next Step:                     Use the
>   following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup
>   process again.   Component name:                SQL Server Setup
>   Support Files   Component error code:          2337   Component log
>   file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log   Error
>   description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected
>   error. The error code is 2337. Could not close file:
>   Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.dll GetLastError:
>   0.   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%402337
>
> Feature:                       Setup Support Files   Status:
>   Failed: see logs for details   Reason for failure:            An error
>   occurred during the setup process of the feature.   Next Step:
>   Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the
>   setup process again.   Component name:                SQL Server Setup
>   Support Files   Component error code:          2337   Component log
>   file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1.log   Error
>   description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected
>   error. The error code is 2337. Could not close file:
>   Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.dll GetLastError:
>   0.   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%402337
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Added the contents of the summary file

Comment: Hey, Chris.  Could you share the contents of "Detail.txt" from that same log file path (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191213_084422\)?

Comment: @JoshDarnell How can I share it? Its about 25000 lines long.

Comment: Oh!  Well yeah, I guess you can't share the whole thing.  Do you see anything that looks like an error?  Search for "at Microsoft" or "Error: "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to an issue with the install media. I received an ISO from our server team initially. After I encountered the issue with that I went and downloaded an ISO myself from the Microsoft Volume Licensing site. Again, ran into the same issue. Microsoft support was unable to pinpoint why the error was occurring.

Final solution was to download the [SQL Server 2016 Developer](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=sql%20server). Install from that ran first time without any issue.